# Javascript only work for first block?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all please bear with me I'm a newbie ^^

I wanna make a checkbox list:

- checkbox 1
- checkbox 2
- checkbox 3

if checkbox 1 is checked, block_1 will be displayed, and so on,
but it only works for the first block, if I move block_2 above block_1 it'll be the one that's working, what's wrong?

```js
function show(id) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
  var checkList = document.getElementById("block_" + id);
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    checkList.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    checkList.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="show(1)"> Concrete <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="show(2)"> Soil Mechanics <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="show(3)"> Hidraulics <br>
<hr>

<div id="block_1" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment A <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment B <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment C <br>
<div>

<div id="block_2" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment D <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment E <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment F <br>
<div>

<div id="block_3" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment G <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment H <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment I <br>
<div>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JS code is fine. The real problem is your HTML. Close your div tags. This is creating behavioral issues with the code

```
<div id="block_1" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment A <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment B <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment C <br>
</div>

<div id="block_2" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment D <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment E <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment F <br>
</div>

<div id="block_3" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment G <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment H <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment I <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. Each closing tag to your `<div>` block is missing the `/` character; add it to look like `</div>`
2. Your `id` attributes are incorrect.  As specified in the [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) spec, they must contain at least one character.  For [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) they much start with a character.  To avoid other quirks, do not use only numbers.

Below includes these changes:

```js
function show(id) {
  let checkBox = document.getElementById('check_' + id),
      checkList = document.getElementById('block_' + id);

  checkList.style.display = checkBox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_1" onclick="show(1)"> Concrete <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_2" onclick="show(2)"> Soil Mechanics <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_3" onclick="show(3)"> Hidraulics <br>
<hr>

<div id="block_1" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment A <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment B <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment C <br>
</div>

<div id="block_2" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment D <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment E <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment F <br>
</div>

<div id="block_3" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment G <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment H <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment I <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with closing `div` tags

```js
function show(id) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
  var checkList = document.getElementById("block_" + id);
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    checkList.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    checkList.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="show(1)"> Concrete <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="show(2)"> Soil Mechanics <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="show(3)"> Hidraulics <br>
<hr>

<div id="block_1" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment A <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment B <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment C <br>
</div>

<div id="block_2" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment D <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment E <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment F <br>
</div>

<div id="block_3" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment G <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment H <br>
  <input type="checkbox"> experiment I <br>
</div>
```